# Read db data in Cloud Functions in Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In firebase documentation I didn't find a simple way to get data from firebase db - only by events (.on, .once). Is this the only way?

In this case, to get data from different branches, I need to describe handler in handler? And response.send() must be in deepest handler?

Is this the correct function?

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
var db = admin.database();

db.ref("test/val").once("value", snap => {
    var val1 = snap.val();
    db.ref("test/val").set(val1+1);
    db.ref("test2/val").once("value", snap => {
        var val2 = snap.val();
        response.send(val1+", "+val2);
    });
});

//response.send("bad way");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you need to make sure you wait for all asynchronous work to complete (your `set` does not get waited on). I've reworked it a bit to use promises instead of callbacks to make the flow clear:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  var db = admin.database();

  var val1, val2;
  db.ref("test/val").once("value").then(snap => {
    val1 = snap.val();
    return db.ref("test/val").set(val1+1);
  }).then(() => {
    return db.ref("test2/val").once("value');
  }).then(snap => {
    val2 = snap.val();
    response.send(val1+", "+val2);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    response.send("error occurred");
  });
});
```